# Choice and Errorlevel?

Tags: batch-file

I do something like this:

```
echo 1-exit
echo 2-about
echo 3-play
choice /c 123 >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto exit
if errorlevel 2 goto about
if errorlevel 3 goto play
:play
blah
:about
blah
:exit
cls
```

If I select the "play" option, it exits. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 12):

The `if errorlevel` expression evaluates to true if actual error level returned by choice is greater or equal to given value. So if you hit 3, the first if expression is true and script terminates. Call `help if` for more information.

There are two simple workarounds.

First one (better) - replace `if errorlevel` expression with actual comparision of `%ERRORLEVEL%` system variable with a given value:

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" goto exit
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "2" goto about
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "3" goto play
```

Second one - change order of comparisions:

```
if errorlevel 3 goto play
if errorlevel 2 goto about
if errorlevel 1 goto exit
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use the %errorlevel% value to directly go to the desired label:

```
echo 1-exit
echo 2-about
echo 3-play
choice /c 123 >nul
goto option-%errorlevel%
:option-1
rem play
blah
:option-2
rem about
blah
:option-3
exit
cls
```